# Cursor "pointer" when the mouse selecting text

Tags: css

What is the best solution to set cursor pointer when the mouse selecting text? On firefox the cursor remains the one set as you select the text, instead of Chrome as you select the text, the cursor will return to the standard one.

Comment: have you tried in CSS `cursor: pointer` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in CSS3:

```
::-moz-selection
{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

for FF; and for other browsers use:

```
::selection
{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
cursor:pointer;
```

to your CSS

```
.myClass {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```